# calculating Correlation between each of 103 first columns and each of the 106 next, 12 repeated times

Tags: r

I have a  (144, 1378) df ; it is made of 13 experiments for 106 parameters.

The first group is the reference group. I want to calculate the corr of each of the 106 parameter, for each group, IN RELATION WITH the first group.

That is, for example, calculate the corr of column 107 with column 1 
-> return result withe name of the parameter and the group.

Then the corr of column 213 (107 + 106) with column 1 ... till the column 1272 with column 1...

But I have trouble in fixing the first 106 columns as a basis of reference :-(.

```
MK_comp_par1 <-sapply(seq(1, 1378, by=106),function(i) cor(bind_sc[,i:(i+1)], method ="kendall", use = "complete"))
```

Comment: You might find `focus()` from the corrr package useful. Here's a post: https://drsimonj.svbtle.com/how-does-one-variable-correlate-with-all-others

Answer (score 2):

you must be looking for something like this:

```
bind_sc <- matrix(replicate(144*1378, rnorm(1)), nrow = 144)
i <- seq(1, 1378, by=106) 
j <- seq(0, 105, by=1) 
Res = list()
Res <- lapply(j,function(j,i)
{ 
    cor(x=bind_sc[,j+1], y=bind_sc[,i+j], method ="kendall", use = "complete")
},i)
```

the [[i]] value of the list of Res is the correlation between the i-th column of your data with the corresponding data in other experiments. hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this without some example data, but it should work:

```
MK_comp_par1 <- mapply(function(x,y) cor(bind_sc[,c(x,y)], method = "kendall", 
                                         use = "complete"), seq(1, 106), seq(107, 1378))
```

This should work as the second vector is an exact multiple from the first, so `mapply` will start at `1` for `x` every 106 iterations.

Beware that this will probably give you a list of output with length 1272, which you might want to split by 106 to get a list of correlation matrices for each experiment.